# cuda undefined reference to __constant__ array

Tags: linker, cuda, undefined-reference

i got the following problem using nvcc.
I use separate compilation (finally got it running with [cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683575/cuda-5-0-separate-compilation-of-library-with-cmake)) and got a problem with the declaration of a `__device__ __constant__ (extern) type1<type2> var[length]` array.

Here is my header:

```
#include <type.h>
#include <type2.h>

#ifndef GUARD_H_
#define GUARD_H_

namespace NameSpace1{
  namespace NameSpace2{

    namespace Constants{
      __device__ __constant__ extern Type1<Type2> array[10];
      __device__ Type1<Type2> accessConstantX(size_t index);
    }
  }
}
#endif
```

And her my .cu-file:

```
#include <header.h>
#include <assert.h>

namespace NameSpace1{
  namespace NameSpace2{

    namespace Constants{
      __device__ Type1<Type2> accessConstantX(size_t index){
    assert(index <= 9);
    return array[index];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error from intermediate separate compilation step:

```
nvlink error   : Undefined reference to '_ZN12NameSpace115NameSpace29Constants17arrayE'
```

This results from the access in the .cu-file.
Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: due to namespace difference 'NameSpace2' ?

Comment: Constant memory can't be declared `extern`AFAIK.

Comment: @rps corrected it, was a typo in my post (corrected it) but it's correct in my code.

Comment: @talonmies thanks for the tip I tried to not declare it extern, but then I get a problem with multiple definitions. I don't understand why because I only define it in header file and want to access it from a .cu file which contains the host-based initialization and an other one which is the one above to access the values in my kernel. Any idea how to achieve what I need? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: You must *define* it somewhere, exactly once. When you had it declared `extern` it wasn't being defined anywhere. Without it being `extern` you are defining it everywhere.

Comment: @talonmies I removed the `extern` I figured out why this is wrong. I get a multiple definition error for each file which includes the .h-file. I tried to add `namespace Constants{
    extern __device__ __constant__ Type1<Type2> array[10] }` at the beginning a file including the .h. I use the other two namespaces in all device files so this shouldn't be the problem. Unfortunately this doesn't fix it, neither does it result in a new error.

Comment: Are you sure you understand what the difference between a declaration and a definition is in C++? A \_\_constant\_\_ variable must be (statically) *defined* once somewhere in your code, just like a subroutine or a class method.

Comment: @talonmies turned out I didn't understand the difference for variables. But after finding this problem I read some [info](http://www.cprogramming.com/declare_vs_define.html) on this and thought that my solution in the previous comment should work. As it turns out it doesn't but I don't understand why because I define it in the .h-file and declare it using `extern` in the file I use it. **EDIT:** I think that this wrong, I shouldn't need any extern if I include the.h file right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23855/discussion-between-soriak-and-talonmies)

Answer (score 1):

I found out what my mistake was, be reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578635/declaring-a-global-in-a-global-header-file).
It turned out that I didn't understand how to correctly declare an global variable in a header file. My problem had nothing to do with nvcc. Thanks @talonmies for your help it pointed my in the direction to look for the answer.

Here the solution to my problem:

Here is my header:

```
#include <type.h>
#include <type2.h>

#ifndef GUARD_H_
#define GUARD_H_

namespace NameSpace1{
  namespace NameSpace2{

    namespace Constants{
      extern __device__ __constant__ extern Type1<Type2> array[10];
      __device__ Type1<Type2> accessConstantX(size_t index);
    }
  }
}
#endif
```

And her my .cu-file:

```
#include <header.h>
#include <assert.h>

namespace NameSpace1{
  namespace NameSpace2{

    namespace Constants{
      __device__ __constant__ Type1<Type2> array[10];
      __device__ Type1<Type2> accessConstantX(size_t index){
        assert(index <= 9);
        return array[index];
      }
    }
  }
}
```